# Node.js & Express: template engine for plain html code

Tags: node.js, express

Using Node.js and express in a MEAN environment, I am looking for a simple and straightforward template engine, meeting these requirements:

- does not dictate me to only use its own weird syntax but allows me to keep writing webpages using pure/plain html and js
- supports conditional includes
- works with express
- operates on server-side (Node.js/Express)
- executes freakin' fast ;)

Basically I just want to slice my webpage into several modules (e. g. header, footer, ...) and include those now and then based on simple conditions. I don't want to entirely (re-)rebuild all webpages using a proprietary template language but rather prepare a few html modules that I concatenate at runtime (comparable to PHP where I just use the include instruction to paste prepared html code). 
I had a look at http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/ and https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/modules#templating but the sites seem outdated and according to them, there ain't no template engine available fully meeting my requirements!? 
Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Jade can be an option. http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: You'll probably want to use [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) which stands for Embedded JavaScript. You can use normal HTML syntax in it.

Comment: Can I use EJS on server side?

Comment: John, so jade also allows plain HTML/JS? I thought I had to use its weird syntax?

Comment: you can use js in jade using script tags: http://jade-lang.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ejs is more natural for what you are looking for https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application, but jade can work also. The example in the link uses partials, which you dont need to use if ur just rendering a single page

Comment: looks promising. i'll check it out. thanks for now =)